# CSV Read specific row chosen by finding a specific data value

Tags: python, excel, csv

**Background:** Electrical Engineer with some programming experience

**Problem:**
I have a CSV file that follows this format:

| TimeTag | DataItem | label (decimal) | label (Octal) | ParsedData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time1 | Item1 | ### | ### | Data |
| time2 | Item4 | ### | ### | Data |
| time3 | Item2 | ### | ### | Data |
| ...... | ...... | .............. | ............ | ......... |

This CSV file is already parsed from multiple .bin files but contains far too much info if you are looking for specific data points. I am writing a script that will find where for the **DataItem** = Altitude the **ParsedData** changes from 0 to positive. This is a take-off event. After finding this specific event I want to grab the **TimeTag** at which it happens. My logic is:

Open Excel File
Identify rows containing **DataItem** Altitude
For these rows, find where **ParsedData** changes from 0 to positive.
For this specific row, identify the related **TimeTag**

I can easily find the information I need by using the **Insert** -> **Table** function in excel; however, I have many files to get through and would like to find a way to automate the process. I am currently looking through Pandas documentation for any useful functions.

Comment: Is it a CSV file, or is it an Excel spreadsheet?  There's no need to drag Excel in for such a simple task.  Just a simple loop through the rows, ignoring lines where DataItem doesn't match, tracking the last remembered ParsedData.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just as you have described it, then this should do the job:

```
import csv

for row in csv.DictReader(open('mydata.csv')):
    if row['DataItem'] == 'Altitude' and row['ParsedData'] > 0:
        print(row['TimeTag'])
        break
```

Comment: Hi. I read OP's prompt, "the DataItem = Altitude the ParsedData changes from 0 to positive", to mean you should break when DataItem does in fact equal Altitude... not the not-equal you have now.

Comment: You're right, I started out intending to use a "continue" and changed my mind without reversing the comparison.